# Django TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not News_Channel

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

Thisi is my login view.

```
def login(request):
    username = request.data.get("username")
    password = request.data.get("password")
    if username is None or password is None:
        return Response({'error': 'Please provide both username and password'},
                        status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if not user:
        return Response({'error': 'Invalid Credentials'},
                        status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    voting_result = Count.objects.filter(userId=user.id)
    print(voting_result)
    channel = {}

    for e in voting_result:
        channel[e.channelId] = e.rate
    return Response({'token': token.key, 'user': user.username, 'email': user.email, 'id': user.id, 'stats': channel},
                    status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

I want to add a dictionary **channel** in my response. But I am getting this error.

```
keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not News_Channel
```

What should I do so that I have **channel** dictionary also in my response? I will use it in my react app.

Comment: full error would be helpful, but I guess this is type error on line: `channel[e.channelId]=..`. Thing is - python dict keys must be hashable (immutable) objects like str, int and etc. Key cannot be dict, list or News_Channel if it is not hashable. Again - cannot tell for sure because you pasted only part of the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python dicts can process only immutable hashable keys, like str, int, float, bool, tuple, frozenset etc. If an entity isn't hashable or is mutable, it can't be the dictionary key. If you want to use `e.channelId` as key, you should convert it to string, for example:

`channel[str(e.channelId)] = e.rate`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need `channelId` id as key

Try:

```
for e in voting_result:
    channel[e.channelId.id] = e.rate
```